# Pandas read_excel can't read an xls but xlrd can

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd

Im trying to parse an excel file, I normally use pandas read_excel(), however for this particular excel it returns an empty DataFrame with no errors. I believe read_excel uses xlrd under the hood so I switched to xlrd to get an error message, but xlrd worked without issue... Both modules come from an anaconda 4.0 installation with python v3.5

```
> df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsm")
> df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
> book = xlrd.open_workbook("test.xlsm")
> book.sheet_names()
['HowTo', 'Version History', 'VersionList', 'List']
> pd._version
<module 'pandas._version' from '/home/-/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/_version.py'>
> xlrd.info
<module 'xlrd.info' from '/home/-/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xlrd/info.py'>
```

Module openpyxl also worked. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: What do you get with `df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsm", sheet_names=None)`

Comment: That's not an `xls` file. `xlsm` is an `xlsx` file with macros. Even libraries that read this won't be able to execute the macros. `xls` is the obsolete format replaced by `xlsx` 14 years ago

Comment: Pandas now uses openpyxl by default and xlrd has dropped support for XLSX so you should check your versions and relevant release notes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're right, I used xls meaning excel. I tried saving the file as an old style xls and without macros xlsx, but the result is the same, I don't use the macros I just want to read some cell values...

Comment: @CharlieClark good point I followed read_excel() in the installed libraries (pandas/io/excel) and it can use both openpyxl or xlrd based on 'engine' parameter. I think openpyxl is the default. I tried it with xlrd using
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsm", engine='xlrd') 
but the result is the same

Comment: @QuangHoang I tried sheet_names=None it didn't make a difference